# How to calculate age percentage over total in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Considering my documents are structured like the one below, I'm trying to calculate the percentage of people with a certain age over the total number of people (each document is a single person).

```
{ 
  "codf": "002",
  "nome": "Debora",
  "cognome": "Palermo",
  "datanascita": "1953-01-17"
  "age": 41
}
```

What I tried so far is in the linked Mongo playground below: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8KF9M7f3PIT

Basically, I successfully calculated the total number of people with a certain age, but I'm failing to calculate the total amount of people in the collection to actually calculate the percentage, that because if I use the `$count` operator, it aggregates the documents and I don't want that.

The output should look like this:

```
{ 
  "age": 41,
  "percentage_with_age": <actual_percentage>
}
```

Comment: It is good, that you provided a play, however you should reduce the sample data and put only the relevant fields.

Comment: **Are these samples real data??** - they contain sensitive medical information, names  and address of person, phone number, medical diagnostics and treatments.

Comment: Do you think `$round` calculates the proper age of a person?

Comment: No the samples are not real data, they are auto generated. All the names and phone numbers are random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the age properly I would suggest this way:

```
age: {
   $subtract: [
      { $subtract: [{ $year: "$$NOW" }, { $year: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }] },
      { $cond: [{ $lt: [{ $dayOfYear: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }, { $dayOfYear: "$$NOW" }] }, 0, 1] }
   ]
}
```

Then to get the percentage you can use this one:

```
db.pazienti.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         datanascita: { $toDate: "$datanascita" },
         age: {
            $subtract: [
               { $subtract: [{ $year: "$$NOW" }, { $year: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }] },
               { $cond: [{ $lt: [{ $dayOfYear: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }, { $dayOfYear: "$$NOW" }] }, 0, 1] }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: "$age", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         total: { $sum: "$count" },
         age: { $push: { count: "$count", age: "$_id" } }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         age: {
            $map: {
               input: "$age",
               in: {
                  age: "$$this.age",
                  count: "$$this.count",
                  percentage_with_this_age: { $round: [{ $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$$this.count", "$total"] }, 100] }, 2] }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$age" },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$age" } },
   { $sort: { age: 1 } }
])
```

Or you can also first run `$unwind`:

```
db.pazienti.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         datanascita: { $toDate: "$datanascita" },
         age: {
            $subtract: [
               { $subtract: [{ $year: "$$NOW" }, { $year: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }] },
               { $cond: [{ $lt: [{ $dayOfYear: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }, { $dayOfYear: "$$NOW" }] }, 0, 1] }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: "$age", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         total: { $sum: "$count" },
         age: { $push: { count: "$count", age: "$_id" } }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$age" },
   {
      $set: {
         age: "$age.age",
         count: "$age.count",
         percentage_with_this_age: { $round: [{ $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$age.count", "$total"] }, 100] }, 2] },
         total: "$$REMOVE"
      }
   },
   { $sort: { age: 1 } }
])
```

If you prefer `$facet`:

```
db.pazienti.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         datanascita: { $toDate: "$datanascita" },
         age: {
            $subtract: [
               { $subtract: [{ $year: "$$NOW" }, { $year: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }] },
               { $cond: [{ $lt: [{ $dayOfYear: { $toDate: "$datanascita" } }, { $dayOfYear: "$$NOW" }] }, 0, 1] }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $facet:
         {
            age: [{ $group: { _id: "$age", count: { $sum: 1 } } }],
            total: [{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }]
         }
   },
   { $unwind: "$age" },
   {
      $set: {
         age: "$age._id",
         count: "$age.count",
         percentage_with_this_age: { $round: [{ $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$age.count", { $first: "$total.count" }] }, 100] }, 2] },
         total: "$$REMOVE"
      }
   },
   { $sort: { age: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Your answer worked, also calculating age this way is definitely better. In the meantime I found a solution to calculate the percentage using the `$facet` operator but it ended up being an extremely long query. Switched to your method.

Comment: Actually using `$facet` does not make a big difference, see my update.